# How to access path contains photo folder by expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm using `downloadAsync` from [FileSystem](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem.html#expofilesystemdownloadasyncuri-fileuri-options) of Expo to download an image. It returns an image into the folder from `Expo.FileSystem.cacheDirectory`. But I don't know how to download the image into photo folder on a device.
Plz help me [image]

This is an `uri` was returned after downloaded `file:///Users/hoaitruong/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/937033C0-A523-4F7E-88E0-C203329FDDC3/data/Containers/Data/Application/8459E190-D882-43BE-9E16-3C219D325EAC/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fsigma-b280412d-e7ec-4029-a358-68197e79cfaa/img-5843_orig.jpg`

Here is my code:

`FileSystem.downloadAsync(
  attachment.imageUrl,
  FileSystem.cacheDirectory + attachment.fileName
)`

Answer (score 0):

Change `FileSystem.cacheDirectory` to `FileSystem.documentDirectory`